# Настоящий задира любит швырять песком... Тире, двоеточие или что?

Tags: общие-вопросы, бсп

Из художественной литературы:

*Настоящий задира любит швырять песком в людей(?) **в этом он черпает глубокое удовлетворение.***

1. **Вариативность** высокая (почему?).
2. На что же ориентироваться при выборе знака? Лексика, грамматика, интонация — что **определяет** решение?

Может, **правила?** Но их так много, все не выучишь, всю **теорию** разве освоишь! А мне бы только **правильно написать.**..

Или лучше уж **по интуиции**?

3. Это  **практика**, на которой всегда проверяется **теория**.

Comment: Я мог бы по справочнику Розенталя ответить. Почему его закрыли?!

Comment: Не повезло вам...  Так отвечайте, по интуиции. Или по теории, варианты есть))

Comment: А почему его всë-таки закрыли? Хотя вряд ли вы знаете... В любом случае мне пишут «Not found 404, сайт временно недоступен».

Comment: Я знаю, они аренду не оплатили.  За все надо платить...

Comment: Ясненько. В общем, нашел его справочник в другом месте, смотрите мой ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Настоящий задира любит швырять песком в людей, — в этом он черпает глубокое удовлетворение***.

По [справочнику Розенталя (другой сайт) (страница 188, пункт 2),](https://fileskachat.com/view/6297_0615b6d6ee1ed6ee5ad4ad0491ef6601.html) нужно ставить запятую и тире, здесь как раз такой случай:

> 2.Запятая   и   тире  ставятся   между   двумя   частями   бессоюзногосложного     предложения,     из     которых     вторая     носитприсоединительный   характер   с   различными   дополнительнымиоттенками   значения   (пояснительными,  временными,   условно-следственными и др.); нередко эта часть начинается местоименнымисловами  тот, так, та  кой  и т.п.3:  Но дай-ка мы выедем в поле стобою, — ты скоро бы пить запросил у меня (Тв.); Ситанов относитсяко мне дружески, — этим я обязан моей толстой тетради, в которойзаписаны стихи (М.Г.); Нижняя доска обмазывалась коровьим навозом и три раза поливалась водой на морозе, — послеэтого она делалась как зеркало (А.Т.); Она сидела неподалёку на скамьепод покосившимся деревянным грибом, — такие делают в лагерях длячасовых (Пауст.); Значит, то был не Родион, — тот из любой бездныоткликнулся бы ей  (Леон.);  Все предметы вокруг были отчётливы ипреувеличенно реальны, — так бывает, когда не спишь всю ночь (Ш.).

Comment: Очень хороший ответ, Максим, голос от меня. Вроде бы все сходится, но я все-таки сомневаюсь... А вдруг не все дополнительные оттенки выражены. Подождем другие ответы.

Comment: @Sharon Спасибо! Хорошо, давайте подождëм. Если что-то найду, дополню.

Comment: Да, спасибо, поищите. Мне хотелось бы примерить и другие варианты.  И посмотрите вопрос о фразеологизме. Мне кажется, вы могли бы дать на него  ответ.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за ответ, вы здесь самый правильный участник) Быстро учитесь, скоро всех догоните и перегоните)  У автора стоял интересный и несколько неожиданный знак – точка с запятой. Об этом стоит подумать и взять на заметку.  Вероятно, мыслилась бОльшая  самостоятельность, чем при едином знаке.

Comment: Спасибо!) А что вы имеете в виду под _догоните и перегоните_? В каком плане?)

Comment: Спасибо ещë раз! А что про Леопольда? Как понять, что он закончил образование и всë знает?

Comment: А, хорошо, понятно, спасибо за объяснение. Есть такое.